# How do I extract ID's from this array without making an unnecessary DB call?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

In my controller I have extracted all the files that are in trashcan like this:

```
@myfiles = Myfile.all.where("user_id = ? AND trashcan = ?", current_user.id, 1).order('created_at DESC')
```

How do I fetch all the ID's of the myfiles that have been collected?

Comment: What is the need for calling `all` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`pluck`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck):

```
@myfiles = Myfile.all.where("user_id = ? AND trashcan = ?", current_user.id, 1).order('created_at DESC')
myfiles_ids = @myfiles.pluck(:id)
```

Comment: Sorry if i wasn't clear, I want both the @myfiles collection and ID's to be stored in another variable.

Comment: @SwaathiK I don't know exactly what is exactly your intention, but I edited my answer to store ids in another variable.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. :) I'll accept your answer once my timer runs out.